# view code (learn markdown feature)

Tags: feature-request

To learn stack overflow markdown (i.e. last I see is how write snippet run "on the fly") I often use to click on "edit" to simply view markdown code.
For this can be useful a link "view code" after "share | edit | flag" links, specially for users don't have permission of edit post, just to see HOW write some special feature (to learn from who's expert on Stack Overflow).

Comment: The only people who don't have permission to edit posts are people who have had a large number of edits rejected.  Everyone else can edit posts.

Comment: @Servy This could be useful on Meta, however- I've personally seen several tricks I'd love to try, but unless the post is edited, I can't see it easily. But on the main site, I agree: Just clicking "edit" doesn't hurt anything, so long as you don't change and alter the post.

Comment: @Kendra Posts can be edited (just to view the markdown) easily enough on meta too...

Comment: @Servy That's not what I mean. I only have 200 rep- The edit function is unavailable to me on Meta. To get it edited, I'd have to either comment or wait for someone to edit it. Sometimes that doesn't happen, or I don't want to fill the comments with noise.

Comment: @Kendra You can suggest an edit, even if you can't apply one without review, and since you don't need to actually submit anything that's not an issue; you're perfectly capable of using the "edit" link to view the markdown of a meta post.

Comment: @Servy on this post http://i.stack.imgur.com/bN5ND.png (for me, less than 2k rep) the edit button is disabled, making it impossible for me to see the markdown - there are no suggested edits on meta.SO.  This is sometimes useful for questions regarding markdown itself.

Comment: @Servy Are you sure we're talking of the same Meta? On Meta SE, I can- But it's a stand-alone. On Meta SO, where I am most of the time if I'm browsing a meta, there are no suggested edits.

Comment: @Servy for me, the 'edit' links are always greyed out on Meta (like on this question for example).  I am not aware of having had a large number of edits rejected - indeed, I haven't ever edited anything on Meta.  I don't want to edit but I would like to view the markdown.  So if 'edit' is disabled it would be useful to have a 'view source' link.

Answer (score 2):

When "edit" links aren't available for some reason (for example, lower-rep users on Meta sites) you can manually construct a URL to go to the Revisions page of any post, and then use the "source" link on that page to view the Markdown of any revision.

The template for the URL is:

```
<site>/posts/<post id>/revisions
```

For example, the URL to see the revisions of this question is:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/272246/revisions

Comment: While this is a great workaround, it would still be nice to have a direct way to do this for those of us under 2k. :)